Relative Imports of Local Modules in ArcPro (3.2+) Python Script Tool from .atbx Toolbox
I have a library and associated ArcGIS Toolbox set up such that:
/root
├── Toolbox.atbx
├── mylib
│   └── my_function.py
├── my_tools
│   └── my_gp_script.py

I keep my development clone of the code repository in one location on my companies shared server, and host a copy up on GitHub. As I make updates I sync the shared version that other people at my company can access to run the tools provided in the toolbox. As a result I need this structure to be relative and portable.
Each tool inside the toolbox has embedded code that executes the script tool inside the my_tools folder: exec(open('my_tools/my_gp_script.py').read()) these scripts then compile & modify the needed parameters via arcpy, and execute a function such as my_function.py.
This was all working well and good until the ArcPro 3.2 update (though technically I jumped from 3.1 to 3.3) where the way Python script tools are execute from within a toolbox was changed.
See this for reference from ESRI (Scroll down to Python Script Tools, second response down): https://community.esri.com/t5/python-documents/python-in-arcgis-pro-3-2-faq/ta-p/1348851
This gist of it is:
At 3.1 the value in __file__ was:
During execute : C:\Path\MyToolbox.atbx#MyTool_MyToolbox.py
At 3.2 the value in __file__ is:
During execute : C:\Path\MyToolbox.atbx\MyTool.tool\tool.script.execute.py
Following this change, my_gp_tool.py is no longer able to directly call import mylib, because it's now being executed from within a different directory than the source Toolbox.
I've got a temp solution in place wherein I can add sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__.split(".atbx")[0])) to the start of each of my scripts, however this seems a bit smelly to me. It also adds that directory to the python path for the entire ArcPro session, since a single python kernel is loaded up each time you boot up the program--which seems like it could have other unintended effects.
Has anyone else dealt with this particular update issue? Should I reconfigure how I have my root folder laid out? I rather liked having the root be relatively clean with the toolbox, and then essentially a scripts folder (my_tools), and a library folder (mylib), but maybe this was wrong from the start. I don't really want to have folks install my library on their user settings since this would make updates a nightmare, and require people to clone the source library and do a bunch of set up that will detract users.
